# How to change the speed of only a single node?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have a enemy `KinematicBody2D` and I want to slow down both it's movement & animation

I tried `Engine.time_scale` but it slows down the entire game,
so is there a way to slow down only a single node without effecting the others ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to do that.

---

For your `KinematicBody2D` you could do something like this:

```
export var speed_factor := 1.0

func _process(delta:float) -> void:
    delta *= speed_factor
    #...

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    delta *= speed_factor
    #...
```

---

And for your `AnimationPlayer` you can set `playback_speed` (which you can also specify when you call `play`).

Alternatively you can set `playback_process_mode` to `ANIMATION_PROCESS_MANUAL` and then call `advance` and `seek` (in `_process`, for example) to make it advance.

Comment: huh I thought there might be a simpler way, I don't suppose there might be a way to slow down rigid bodies as well?

Comment: @cak3_lover I don't know how you would slow `RigidBody2D` :/

Comment: I tried `delta *= speed_factor` but how would I get it to effect the horizontal movement of [my character](https://pastecode.io/s/om4xx3rz) which is delta independent?

Comment: @cak3_lover For what I see your `direction` is actually a velocity. Velocity is distance / time. We want to apply a factor to the time. So the factor would be dividing. So... `direction /= speed_factor`.

Comment: That doesn't seem right, if I make `speed_factor=0.5` it would be x2 for direction, here's the [complete code](https://pastecode.io/s/9tui03es) to avoid any confusion

Comment: @cak3_lover Right, my mistake. It is `*=` not `/=`… Because `move_and_slide` will multiply by `delta` internally.

Comment: I tried [that](https://pastecode.io/s/2ousssjv) but then I can't seem to jump